# Passing argument in a recursive PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a recursive Powershell script to call itself with elevated rigths. I want to send the PID of parent process to the child process as an argument. Right now I am trying some thing like this, but it's not working.

```
param($someid)

$myWindowsID = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$myWindowsPrincipal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID)

# Get the security principal for the Administrator role
$adminRole = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator

# Check to see if we are currently running "as Administrator"
if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
{
    Write-Host $PID
    "Child process"
    #Write-Host $someid

    # We are running "as Administrator" - so change the title and background color to indicate this
    $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "(Elevated)"
    $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "DarkBlue"
    Clear-Host
}
else
{
    "Parent process"
    Write-Host $PID

    # We are not running "as Administrator" - so relaunch as administrator
    # Create a new process object that starts PowerShell
    $newProcess = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";

    # Specify the current script path and name as a parameter
    $newProcess.Arguments = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition;
    #$newProcess.Arguments = $PID;

    # Indicate that the process should be elevated
    $newProcess.Verb = "runas";

    # Start the new process
    [int]$arg = $PID
    [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);

    # Exit from the current, unelevated, process

    Exit
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A child process can find its `ParentProcessID` from [WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) (using [Get-WmiObject](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849824.aspx), alias `gwmi`):

```
gwmi win32_process | select ProcessID, ParentProcessID, Name | where {$_.ProcessID -eq "$pid"} |   ft -AutoSize
```

I would probably assign it to a variable for reuse later in your script.

```
$PPI = (gwmi win32_process | select ProcessID, ParentProcessID, Name | where {$_.ProcessID -eq "$pid"} | Select-Object ParentProcessID).ParentProcessID
```

Relevant article: *[How do I determine if a process on Windows "has no parent"?](https://superuser.com/questions/689162/how-to-determine-if-process-in-windows-has-no-parent/689171#689171)*

Comment: Hi, I tried the second way of assigning the PID to a global variable. But it won't work since every time the script executes from the beginning and variables are null. Can't it be done by passing arguments?

Comment: To persist between sessions, you'll need to output the $pid to a registry key or text file so that you can read it from the script the second time it runs.

Comment: So basically you are saying that I can't pass PID as argument in this case?

Comment: well you could, but I don't see the point, because the child process can determine it's own parent without having to pass the pid as argument.

Comment: This is a very specific case. I want child not only to know the PID of parent but some more information, for me passing all the information as the argument is the best approach I could think of. Please let me know how to do that as an answer.